# TinyMce: remove editor instance by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I need to delete a `tinymce` instances from `div` with id `invoice_edit_modal`.
My code is (I get all `textareas` with class `.product_comment` then I try to delete them):

```
var productCommentsFields = $('#invoice_edit_modal .product_comment');
productCommentsFields.each(function(i, obj) {
    var commentOldId = $(this).attr('id');
    tinymce.remove('#invoice_edit_modal #'+commentOldId);
});
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work, because removing the textarea dom elements won't affect the javascript tinymce editor objects.

In case you gave your textareas unique ids you are able to remove those editors easily because the editor id equals your textarea id. Just call for each textarea id: `tinymce.get("your_textarea_id").remove();`

For other cases: To elaborate a bit on how to solve your problem i need to know a bit more about your dom structure. Plus, can you tell me what `tinymce.editors` shows in your console?

I will update this answer after you can get me that info.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the `remove()` method on whichever editor instances you want to get rid of.